# Doubt in derivative problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm in trouble with the following problem:

Give $f(x) = x^3 - 3x + 1$ and $g(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + b$, determine the values of $a$ and $b$ in such a way that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same relative maximum and minimum.

I already know that the relative maximum and minimum can be found though the roots of the derivative, so $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 3$ and $g'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax$. As the roots of $f'(x)$ are both ${-1, 1}$, I imagined to build a system of equations to find $a$ and $b$, but I always end in two 'dummy' equations, do someone know a different way to solve this ?

By the way, the dummy equations are when I substitute ${-1, 1}$ in $g(x)$. The equations are $a + b = 4$ and $a + b = -2$

Comment: When I plug in x=1 and g'(x) = 0, I get a different "a" value as compared to plugging in x = -1 So they may have the same relative minimum and maximum, but not for the same x-values. But these relative extrema can be determined from f(x) which then would allow you to find a corresponding "b" for each "a"

Comment: I would start by computing $f(-1)=3$ and $f(1)=-1$, then finding the roots of $g'(x)$ and computing $g(x)$ at these roots, then trying to match up these results. Is that what you tried? … I just noticed your edit. Why substitute $\pm1$ in $g(x)$? I think it's the *function values* at the relative min and max they want to match up, not the $x$ values.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking in a wrong way, trying to make the relative maximum and minimum on the same $x$ coordinate, now I've made some improvements, with $g(x)% roots as ${0, -2a/3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, we must match up the **function values** at the relative min and max (which, in this case, do not have the same $x$-values).

Since $f'=0$ has $x=\pm1$ as roots, we substitute these critical points into $f$ to obtain $f(-1)=-1+3+1=3$ and $f(1)=1-3+1=-1$. You can verify for yourself that these really are local extrema.

Setting $g'=0$ yields $0=3x^2+2ax=x(3x+2a) \implies x=0,-2a/3$. Substitutng these critical points into $g$ yields $g(0) = 0+0+b=b$ and $g(-2a/3) = -8a^3/27 + 4a^3/9 + b = 4a^3/27 + b$.

For these two function values for $g$, it is a bit difficult to see how they should be matched up with our two function values for $f$, since we can't really tell which one is bigger (since we don't know if $a,b$ are positive or negative). So let's guess.

**Case 1:** Suppose the local minimum is $f(1)=-1=b=g(0)$. Then the local maximum is $f(-1)=3=4a^3/27 + b=g(-2a/3)$. Substituting $b$ and solving for $a$ yields:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{4a^3}{27} - 1 &= 3 \\
\dfrac{4a^3}{27} &= 4 \\
\dfrac{a^3}{27} &= 1\\
a^3 &= 27\\
a &= 3\\
\end{align*}
So one possible solution is $a=3, b=-1$. Verify for yourself that $g(0)=-1$ and $g(-2)=3$ really are the local extrema of $g$.

**Case 2:** Suppose the local minimum is $f(1)=-1=4a^3/27 + b=g(-2a/3)$. Then...?

Comment: Then, $g(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 - 3$ and it doesn't match the requirements, so, It's only valid in the first case, am I right ?

Comment: Actually, you should get $g(x)=x^3-3x^2+3$, which does match the requirements (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=x%5E3-3x%5E2%2B3).